# Latex - Table of contents appearing twice

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing my Thesis document and I have Problem with table of Contents. It appears twice all the time. I tried many ways but could not get any help.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, BCOR1cm,toc=chapterentrywithdots]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

{
    \begin{center}
        \raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{University1.PNG}}
         \raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{DOC.PNG}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}

\begin{center}

\LARGE{\textbf{eksfhsufse sdsdgz hfszudfg sjhdgsdgs}}\\
\vspace{1cm}


\Large{\textbf{Master Thesis}}\\ 
\vspace{0.5cm}
Submitted in Fulfilment of the\\
Requirements for the Academic Degree\\
M.Sc.\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Dept. of Computer Science\\
Chair of Computer Engineering
\end{center}
\vspace{3cm}
Submitted by: ajdadad\\
Student ID: bxdjhasdga\\
Date: 12.12.2016\\
\vspace{0.0cm}\\
Supervising tutor: jdjasda \\
(further supervisors)
\end{titlepage}

%---------------------------------------------------------
% Declaration
%---------------------------------------------------------

{Declaration}
%\blindtext
\\
%\textbf{Keywords: Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, ...max 5}
\vspace{0.0mm}
%setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.0}
\begin{sloppypar}
my content 
\end{sloppypar}
\newpage

%---------------------------------------------------------
% Table of Contents, List of figures, List of Tables
%---------------------------------------------------------
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\section{Theoritical Background}
\subsection{Development of Emissions legislation}
\subsection{Beginning of regulation for Exhaust Emissions}
\subsection{Current Emission regulations}
\subsection{Worldwide Harmonized Light vehicles Test cycle}
\subsection{Portable Emission Measurement system}
\subsection{Real-Drive Emissions}
\section{Software}
\subsection{INCA}
\subsection{Matlab/Simulink}
\subsection{Mil-Desk}
\subsection{Microsoft Visual Studio 2013}
\subsubsection{Programing language C}
\section{Conclusion}
\section{References}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

This is my code. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, the code posted created only one table of contents.

Comment: but my pdf file Shows me two table of Contents.

Comment: `\Large`, like all size comamnds does not take an argument, the syntax is `\LARGE abc` not `LARGE{abc}`

Comment: That might be, but how are we supposed to help, if we cannot reproduce it. How many pages does your pdf have? Please add `Walter Wombat and Carl Capybara are dancing with a duck.` after your first section (introduction) and try again. Does your second toc disappear? Please show a screenshot of the second toc.

Comment: Does the second table of contents also show the page numbers right beside the section titles? If not, can it be that you mistake the section headings as a table of contents, since the text of the sections is still missing?

Comment: yes, the second table of Contents does not Show the page numbers beside section titles. Can you say me how can this be resolved

Comment: And now add the sentence i told you to add and compile again.

Comment: Nothing changes, it seems the same Output appears again

Comment: Add the exact same sentense after *every* `\section` command. Hint: You can use Copy and Paste.

Comment: The first page is the *table of contents*, the second page is the *contents* (and the reason for the first page).

Comment: Nothing is helpful

Comment: I suggest to take a 30 minute break, drink a coffee and come back. You are thinking in the completetly wrong direction. I am serious, take a break.

Comment: After the break, consider replacing the wombat sentence with the real content of your thesis.

Comment: The first line `1 Introduction` is in the TOC. The second one starts the actual chapter called `Introduction`. It _looks_ like the start of a second TOC but it is in the running text. I suggest you move your `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` commands to just after your `\tableofcontents` command, then insert a `\cleardoublepage` command, and put some text in your document. It should then all look fine.

Comment: The `table of contents` is  only one time where it is  your  `\tableofcontents` code.  The content is all the following starting with  `\section{Introduction}`,  but without plain text among  sections titles, seem like a table of contents without number of pages.  Just write  text after each  `\section{...}` and  `\subsection{...}` (e.g,  `\subsection{INCA} Blah blah blah, etc.`) and you will see clearly what  is  the *table of contents* and what is *"only" the content*.

Comment: @user116007 How can the "second" table of contents *be a table of contents* if it *does not* have the title **Contents**? Therefore, since there's only one title saying "Contents" there is only one *table of contents*...

Answer (score 5):

The table of contents (ToC) is showed only one time, just  where it is your `\tableofcontents` code.

The `\section{Introduction}` is not the first line of the ToC, is the title of the first section in the main text. But without normal text among sections titles, the list of titles resemble a table of contents without number of pages.  Just write some text among the   `\section` and `\subsection` lines, e.g.:

```
\subsection{INCA}
The Inca Empire was the largest empire in pre-Columbian America.
```

And you will see the difference.

For a better understanding of the basics, is always better start with a ***minimal*** working example as:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\section{Introduction} 
    This is a little example.
\section{Motivation} 
    Light the way for who is in the dark.
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Not enough clear? May be help a different ToC and colors.
(Also help a lot comment each obscure code):

```
\documentclass{paper}         % Just for see a dotted ToC 
\usepackage{color}            % Just for see another color in the ToC 
\pagestyle{empty}             % Just for no head/foot distraction
\begin{document}              % This start the document
{\color{red}\tableofcontents} % This make a (one) ToC in red 
\color{blue}                  % This turn blue the following content in blue
\section{Introduction}        % This is already the contents !!
    This is a little example. % This is plain text  
\section{Motivation}          % This is another section title
    Light the way for who
 is in the dark.
\end{document}                % This is the end
```

> [image: mwe]