# Customize contents page

Tags: header-footer

How to remove the header on the contents page from one of the corners as seen from the figure given below
[image]

Comment: Putting some of the code on how you got this would be great. However look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333349/latex-table-of-contents-appearing-twice

Comment: For this answer, it would be really helpful, if you could include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Any answer would heavily depend on which document class etc. you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compare `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`. If they are equal on a page then remove e.g. `\rightmark`. This can be done replacing `\rightmark` by `\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}`. `\ifstr` is provided by package `scrbase` or `scrextend` or all KOMA-Script classes. But there are other packages with similar commands too.

Unfortunaly I do not know the class and the package used for header and footer. But here are two examples:

`book` with `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrbase}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

`book` with `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]